# pandas grouped object: sort values within each category without disturbing the category order

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas Dataframe (below) and I want to do a very simple thing: within each Climate_type without disturbing the order of Climate_type:

```
Climate_type    Crop        
h. continental  cabbage         200.148148
                green_beans     226.925926
                potato          316.981481
                winter_wheat    292.333333
subtropical     cabbage         519.925926
                green_beans     338.833333
                potato          365.740741
                spring_wheat    278.388889
temperate       cabbage         141.259259
                green_beans     165.814815
                potato          238.333333
                winter_wheat    163.425926
Name: Total_Irrigation_mm, dtype: float64
```

When I use sort I get the following:

```
Climate_type    Crop        
temperate       cabbage         141.259259
                winter_wheat    163.425926
                green_beans     165.814815
h. continental  cabbage         200.148148
                green_beans     226.925926
temperate       potato          238.333333
subtropical     spring_wheat    278.388889
h. continental  winter_wheat    292.333333
                potato          316.981481
subtropical     green_beans     338.833333
                potato          365.740741
                cabbage         519.925926
Name: Total_Irrigation_mm, dtype: float64
```

You see that the order of the Climate_type is not preserved any more which is not what I want.

Comment: do you get the desired output if you pass param `sort=False` to `groupby`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by grouping on `Climate_type`, and then sort within each group:

```
In [54]: s.groupby(level=0, group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.order())

Out[54]: 
Climate_type   Crop        
h.continental  cabbage         200.148148
               green_beans     226.925926
               winter_wheat    292.333333
               potato          316.981481
subtropical    spring_wheat    278.388889
               green_beans     338.833333
               potato          365.740741
               cabbage         519.925926
temperate      cabbage         141.259259
               winter_wheat    163.425926
               green_beans     165.814815
               potato          238.333333
dtype: float64
```

Note: the `group_keys=False` is needed to not have Climate_type duplicated in the result.